# Foundation - Text goes on behind the footer

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation to build my website and I tried to make my footer responsive.
I followed the steps from the [official tutorial](https://foundation.zurb.com/learn/building-a-responsive-footer-with-foundation-6-gary-jenning.html).

For my footer is use this code:

```
<footer>
  <div class="wrap row small-up-1 medium-up-1 align-center">
    <div class="column"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="register.html">Lorem</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="impressum.html">Lorem</a></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The css looks like this:

```
footer{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  color:white;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

This works fine when I only have a small amount of text. But when i put a lot of text on my page the text goes behind the footer and further.
It looks like [this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASuaj.png)

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong. The outcome should be that the footer is always on the bottom.
Thank you in advance!

Edit:
Here is a fiddle so you can see what my problem is: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/detzinger/bL4fzc1v/3/)

Comment: It will be more helpful if you share a fiddle for this, so we can inspect the problem more clearly.

Comment: @vishulgarg Added it

Comment: it seems your footer is inside a container div which has position relative and footer is stuck to bottom of that div as it has position absolute and bottom. Do you have a container in which footer resides if yes then where is it positioned?

Comment: @PriteshThaker Not really. The footer is in the body tag without any other tags surrounding it

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the bottom margin to the `main` element and wrap all content in it?